# Acessing variables from turtles in agentset

Tags: netlogo

Suppose each turtle have a `variable`. If I want to access the neighbors of a turtle, I should use:

```
turtles-on neighbors
```

This will create an agentset for each turtle. How do I create a list that contains the value of `variable`in each turtle? My intent is to find the mean value of `variable` from a given "neighborhood".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that I should first define the neighborhood as a local variable

```
let neighborhood turtles-on neighbors
```

This will allow me to use the newly defined object the way I want. If I want the mean of that object, then:

```
mean [variable] of neighborhood
```

Although trivial, I hope this helps somebody in the future.